# Network monitoring system capable of link functionality (like OpenNMS linkd)

Tags: networking, monitoring, opennms

The [OpenNMS monitoring system](http://www.opennms.org) has the ability to automatically discover and display links between nodes and networking equipment. The module is called [linkd](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Linkd) and is a very handy way of visualizing system layout and tracking switchports and interfaces (e.g. you can see what's connected to a switch and vice-versa).

I'm curious if any of the other monitoring packages out there offer similar functionality, or is the concept of linkd unique to OpenNMS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, SolarWinds' [User Device Tracker](http://www.solarwinds.com/search/user-device-tracker.aspx) is somewhat similar, and should plug into their Orion NPM product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is what you want, but take a look at [NACE](https://launchpad.net/nace) or [netdot](https://osl.uoregon.edu/redmine/projects/netdot). It can create Nagios configuration for monitoring hosts. I also see that the [GroundWork Enterprise edition](http://www.gwos.com/pricing/enterprise-flex/) provide topology discovery feature.